# How to compile a java program when the source code are in some separated files

Tags: java

Recently I am reading Sedgewick's Algorithms. He had written some libraries for input and output which include some static methods. Then he use these static methods in his program. In order to use these methods. He recommend me to download those source code into my working directory. Then I can call these methods directly. I am following his instructs but when I use "javac filename.java" to compile my Java source code in command line. I failed. And compiler tell me that he can't find the methods which I take from the author's libraries.  How to solve this question? thanks very much.

Maybe this question is not qualified to post here. Please forgive me,for I can't find a more rudimentary place in StackExchange to post.

Comment: we need more information.  please post both the EXACT command you are using to compile and the EXACT error messages.  I suspect you are simply not including them in the list of things to compile.  For instance, you can try `javac *.java` to attempt to compile all java files.  Please note that this may not be the desired action.

Comment: You need to add those APIs or source codes to the compile time class-path.

Comment: @RussellUhl  thanks for your advice. I read the error messages and find that I didn't copy the whole code of the libraries.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the author recommend me to put these files in one fold. I guess it will make sure they are in the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the Author's libraries available in your classpath?
If you are running via command line, put these libraries in a folder and set the classpath environment variable.
If you are using an IDE such as eclipse, update the Java build path and add these library.

Comment: thank you. the author also recommend me to put these files into a same folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE lke Eclipse,you can find info from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)
regarding how to add JAR files to your project